# what does ++operator do in this void uart_puts(unsigned char * t) { while(*t) uart_putch(*t++);

Tags: c++, c

What does `++` operator do in this C program?

```
void uart_puts(unsigned char *t) {
    while (*t)
        uart_putch(*t++); //I cant understand the operation here
}
```

Comment: here Uart_putch is another module

Comment: why is the * symbol used before t.Is there any reason or is it comulsary to use while pasing value.

Comment: The * indicates that the variable is not a value, but rather a pointer to a value.  I suggest to google "c pointer tutorial" or similar to get started understanding the line.

Answer (score 4):

Pointer arithmetic:

The sentence uart_putch(*t++) can be discomposed in:

```
uart_putch(*t);  // get actual t unsigned char value
t++; // increments t pointer to next unsigned char
```

Answer (score 0):

**`*t`**   //contains the address of the variable which it points
**`*t++`** //increments its address to point next position.

eg:-

```
int j;
int *k;
k=&j; //assigning k to j's address, so that k pointing the value of j
*k++;//means incrementing the adress to point next
```

Comment: No, `*t` is the dereference of the pointer `t` (`t` contains the address). So `*t` is of the type `unsigned char` here